# Variances of observed values and corresponding beta hats in Linear Regression

Tags: regression, variance

Is there any relation between the variance of the observed values of a predictive variable and the variance of the estimator of the corresponding beta parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! Though it is a bit indirect. Let's let $X$ contain our predictors, including an intercept, centered around their means (which doesn't change their variance at all). The usual variance for the $\hat\beta$s in the regression
$$
E[Y|X] = X\hat\beta
$$
is $$
Var[\hat\beta]=\sigma^2 (X' X)^{-1} = \frac{\sigma^2}{n-1}\left(\frac{X' X}{n-1}\right)^{-1}
$$
The (sample) covariance matrix of the centered predictors is equal to $\text{Cov}[X] = \frac{X' X}{n-1}$, where the diagonals are the variances of the predictors. So you can see how the sample covariance matrix of the predictors plays a part in the variance of the $\hat\beta$s.

Taking the inverse of the predictor covariance matrix makes any direct correspondence between the variances of the predictors and the variance of the coefficients a bit more complicated; even though the variance of a single predictor is the corresponding value on the diagonal of the coefficient variance matrix, you can't just look at the variance of the predictor (i.e., the diagonal of the predictor covariance matrix) because the covariances among the predictors is part of the calculation of the diagonal of the inverse.

Comment: Thank you very much Noah